# Process and tools used in refactoring software

Tags: refactoring

I am looking for re-factoring software for language like C++/Java/C# ... that provide information on how they do re-factoring.

What method they use to detect portion of code that needs re-factoring and how do they keep the program integrity when applying changes. And if possible what tools do they use.

Thanks

Comment: I am not looking to refactore any program here, I just want to know which process re-factoring software use and maybe in the end compare it with manual re-factoring.

Comment: Yes I was looking for open source program but I was planning to read the book you linked.

Comment: @celeriko: I think this is terrible advice. (I take it you have not built a refactoring tool).  No book on refactoring that is intended as a practitioner's handbook on how to do it, is going to address the technology used by tools. How people solve problems, and how compiler-like tools solve problems are radically different. Its fine to read practitioner books to understand the purpose and rough sketches of how to do it by hand, but OP specifically asked for "information on how (tools) do refactoring".

Comment: All: [celeriko suggested reading refactoring books was the answer.  He deleted his comment.  I'm adding this note back so my remark doesn't seem to come from left field].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to understand how refactoring tools work, you need, as a foundation, to learn essentially how compilers work:  parsing, symbol-table construction, various kinds of control and dataflow analysis, program analysis, program transformation.  Refactoring engines build on top of this.

Details on how tools handle specific refactorings tend to be found in the software engineering research literature.  Check out http://scholar.google.com, and use the search term "refactoring"; you'll get buried under papers that address different kinds of refactorings, and different approaches to doing them.

The question about "finding (single) refactoring tools for *list of languages*?" is pretty hard to answer.  Most refactoring tools are difficult to build (see compiler technology discussion above), so you tend not to see "one" tool that does them all, but rather one tool per language/IDE.  Language specific tools are relatively easy to find:  google  "refactoring tool *language*".

One insight, however, is that the machinery to do such refactoring tasks have a lot of basic technology foundations in common in the abstract; see my first paragraph above.
It is unfortunate that the way most refactoring tools are built, is to construct all
this machinery for just the one specific refactoring tool, which helps explain why they are hard to build, therefore expensive to build and therefore rare.    They are also built using traditional compiler techniques (e.g., traditional parsers [with limitations that cause people to continually complain], and procedural programming (after all, that's the way we've done that since the days of the pyramids, right?).

Tools called [program transformation engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) try to instantiate this shared commonality, thereby amortizing the cost of building the baseline across many tasks, and to address the problem of building complex code transformations in easier ways, to make it easier to implement such tasks, by providing non-procedural means to express what needs to be done.

You can see an [example of program transformations applied to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22100670/120163); the message from that example is the same transformation engine can be used to "refactor" code in other languages, which is I think what you were originally trying to ask about.  (Full disclosure: I'm behind the tool in the example).